# How to avoid 'from module import module' when creating a pypi package?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I created a pypi package, and I want to be able to do this:

```
from module import function
```

But it seems i can only access the function if I do:

```
from module import module
module.function()
```

My folder structure looks like this:

```
modulename (folder)
-- setup.py (Setup python file)
-- modulename (folder)
---- modulename.py (Python file with code in it)
---- __init__.py (Empty python file)
```

Comment: delete the `__init__.py` and rename `modulename.py` to  `__init__.py`

Comment: That worked, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If the "packages" and "package_dir" are not supposed to change, you may try to add import statement in (root)/modulename/modulename/__init__.py.

```
from .modulename import function
```